# Parse data and time string to Access Date value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

How can I parse a date/time string into an Access Date object given a certain date- and time format?

I can use the CDate() function like this:

```
  Dim StrDateTime As String
  Dim DtTest As Date

  StrDateTime = "2011-12-31 23:59:59"

  DtTest = CDate(StrDateTime)
  MsgBox DtTest
```

This works, Access recognizes the format, fine, but how can I absolutely be sure that this happens under all circumstances (e.g. Date/Time settings Regional Settings, Access version?). I would like to "tell" CDate my special date/time format.

Other option is this (but a lot of code):

```
  Dim StrDateTime As String
  Dim IntYear As Integer
  Dim IntMonth As Integer
  Dim IntDay As Integer
  Dim IntHour As Integer
  Dim IntMinute As Integer
  Dim IntSecond As Integer

  StrDateTime = "2011-12-31 23:59:59"

  IntYear = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 1, 4))
  IntMonth = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 6, 2))
  IntDay = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 9, 2))
  IntHour = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 12, 2))
  IntMinute = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 15, 2))
  IntSecond = Val(Mid(StrDateTime, 18, 2))

  DtTest = DateSerial(IntYear, IntMonth, IntDay)
  DtTest = DtTest + TimeSerial(IntHour, IntMinute, IntSecond)
  MsgBox DtTest
```

Other advantage of CDate(): it give a Type Mismatch error on a wrong date/time value. DateSerial + TimeSerial recalculates a new date and time, so "2011-12-31 24:59:59" becomes 01/Jan/2012 0:59:59.

Comment: `CDate()` honours the Regional Settings, regardless of version of Access. One disadvantage of `CDate()` is that it does not always give a Type Mismatch when an ambiguous text value does not match Regional Settings e.g. my settings are UK, `Month(CDate("28/04/2011"))` correctly returns `4` (April) but the absurd UK value `Month(CDate("04/28/2011"))` also returns 4 when arguably an error would be more useful.

Comment: Well, what is the definition of an "unambiguous format"? The fact that it's recognized on my computer with my settings doesn't necessarily means it will in every situation? Or am I wrong? Is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" (and other known formats) universal to all systems?

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? And is there no way to explicitly tell CDate() which parse format to use, something like `CDate("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm", StrValue)`?

Comment: In addition to [the answer by HansUp above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7556874/929708), you may also be interested in [this related StackOverflow discussion about parsing dates from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The format *"yyyy-mm-dd"* is an [ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and when encountering it, `CDate()` expects the *"yyyy"* part to be followed by *"mm-dd"*, never by *"dd-mm"*.  So a date string in that format is unambiguous; it represents the same date value regardless of the user's locale.  And `CDate()` will comply.

Furthermore, there is no way to give `CDate()` a date string formatted as *"yyyy-dd-mm"* and get the date value you intend back.  So `CDate("2011-02-01")` will always give you the date value `#Feb 1 2011#` (regardless of your locale), even if you intended that string to represent `#Jan 2 2011#`.  And `CDate("2011-31-01")` will throw a type mismatch error.

Also note that this only works for dates after the year 100.  (See Heinzi's comment.)

Comment: Note that this only works for dates after the year `100`: `CDate("0001-02-03")` yields the 1st Feb. 2003.