# Convert Text to Date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of dates (column A) stored as text in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` which I'm trying to convert to dates, ultimately so that I can do look ups against them.

I've read a few topics on here and tried some of the suggestions, but I can't get anything to work. One was using:

```
Columns("A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "date"
```

This changed the format of the cells to date but didn't actually change the format of the value which was still stored as text.

My understanding is that I need to use CDate() to change the format of the value from text to date. I've tried something like this:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.columns("A").Cells
    c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
Next c
```

Which gives me a type mismatch error. I wondered if this was because I was trying to save date values back into a non-date formatted cell so I tried combining it with the .NumberFormat = "date" above, which didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @user1300244, did you find any answer worth accepting? It is always good to give feedback / rate answers.

Comment: Type mismatch error usually means invalid date like `"1900-13-12"`, `"1900-02-29"`, `"10000-01-01"`, etc. Dates before `"1899-12-30"` result in the generic "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Answer (score 35):

You can use `DateValue` to convert your string to a date  in this instance

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.columns("A").Cells
    c.Value = DateValue(c.Value)
Next c
```

It can convert `yyyy-mm-dd` format string directly into a native Excel date value.

Comment: btw there is also some `TimeValue(...)` and `Const ds = "31.12.19 16:00"` would work for `DateValue(ds) + TimeValue(ds)` at least in a German time format environment

Comment: Great, thanks. Useful even 7 years later :)

Answer (score 34):

You can quickly convert a column of text that resembles dates into actual dates with the VBA equivalent of the worksheet's Data ► Text-to-Columns command.

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
End With
```

Bulk operations are generally much quicker than looping through cells and the VBA's [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) is very quick. It also allows you the freedom to set a MDY vs. DMY or YMD conversion mask that plagues many text imports where the date format does not match the system's regional settings. See [TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215749%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for a complete list of the available date formats available.

> Caveat: Be careful when importing text that *some* of the dates have not already been converted. A text-based date with ambiguous month and day integers may already been converted wrongly; e.g. 07/11/2015 may have been interpreted as 07-Nov-2015 or 11-Jul-2015 depending upon system regional settings. In cases like this, abandon the import and bring the text back in with Data ► Get External Data ► From Text and specify the correct date conversion mask in the Text Import wizard. In VBA, use the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) and specify the xlColumnDataType.

Comment: The DateValue function works better and uses less resource than TextToColumns

Answer (score 15):

Besides other options, I confirm that using

```
c.Value = CDate(c.Value)
```

works (just tested with the description of your case, with Excel 2010). As for the reasons for you getting a type mismatch error, you may check (e.g.) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502802/cdate-type-mismatch-error).

It might be a locale issue.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps:

```
Sub dateCNV()
    Dim N As Long, r As Range, s As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, "A")
        s = r.Text
        r.Clear
        r.Value = DateSerial(Left(s, 4), Mid(s, 6, 2), Right(s, 2))
    Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes that column **A** contains text values like 2013-12-25 with no header cell.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue earlier. Unfortunately I looked at this thread and didn't find an answer which I was happy with. Hopefully this will help others.

Using `VBA.DateSerial(year,month,day)` you can overcome Excel's intrinsic bias to US date format. It also means you have full control over the data, which is something I personally prefer:

```
function convDate(str as string) as Date
  Dim day as integer, month as integer, year as integer
  year  = int(mid(str,1,4))
  month = int(mid(str,6,2))
  day   = int(mid(str,9,2))
  convDate = VBA.DateSerial(year,month,day)
end function
```

Answer (score 3):

This code is working for me

```
Dim N As Long, r As Range
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To N
    Set r = Cells(i, "B")
    r.Value = CDate(r.Value)
Next i
```

Try it changing the columns to suit your sheet

Comment: This is basically the same as @Sam's answer above, except that it uses a For loop instead of a For Each loop. The benefits of a For Each loop are twofold: First, it automatically sets the variable to be equal to the Range in question. Second, it eliminates the need to determine how many cells exist in the range.

Comment: The "xlUp" method of finding the end of a range is awkward and clunky to me. If there were any cells with values after the end of your range it would fail. I much prefer the "For each x in range" logic in Sam's answer. Excel already knows how many cells there are in the range, we don't need to store it as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

To the OP...
I also got a type mismatch error the first time I tried running your subroutine. In my case it was cause by non-date-like data in the first cell (i.e. a header).
When I changed the contents of the header cell to date-style txt for testing, it ran just fine...

Hope this helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

Blast from the past but I think I found an easy answer to this.  The following worked for me.  I think it's the equivalent of selecting the cell hitting F2 and then hitting enter, which makes Excel recognize the text as a date.

```
Columns("A").Select
Selection.Value = Selection.Value
```

Comment: If you have UK-formatted dates (or probably any other format than US) then doing this will often convert UK dates which are supplied as text to US dates in date format. Using the DateValue method in Sam's answer works a lot better than this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got rid of type mismatch by following code:

```
Sub ConvertToDate()

Dim r As Range
Dim setdate As Range

'in my case I have a header and no blank cells in used range,
'starting from 2nd row, 1st column
Set setdate = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)) 

    With setdate
        .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy" 'I have the data in format "dd.mm.yy"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    For Each r In setdate
        r.Value = CDate(r.Value)
    Next r

End Sub
```

But in my particular case, I have the data in format "dd.mm.yy"

Answer (score 0):

For DD-**MM**-YYYY here is a simple workaround to manage string and dates:

insert the date into the string via DD-**MMM**-YYYY
for example 01-11-2017 -> 01-Nov-2017

U can use the FORMAT(date, "dd-**mmm**-yyyy") to input dates into a string from the spread sheet.

Later, when you output it from a string, **it will not confuse the days and months.**

Comment: @GeoffGriswald which answer is the accepted answer?

Comment: The top-voted answer sorry. Didn't notice that it hasn't been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue for me :

```
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(100, 1)).Select

    For Each xCell In Selection

    xCell.Value = CDate(xCell.Value)

    Next xCell
```