# How to format different DOB formats in Excel?

Tags: excel, date-formatting, data-manipulation

The image below shows different formats for DOB, what is the easiest way to format them to dd/mm/yyyy? The dates on the right are correct however the dates on the left are back to front and missing a 0 for all single numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be willing to bet that 08/03/1997 was not originally 08-Mar-1997 but started out as 03-Aug-1997. Same goes for all of the other ambiguous DMY/MDY dates that Excel wrongly converted during the text import. Some dates remained as text because (as in A3) there are not 13 months in a year.

It makes no sense to convert the rest of the data now that half of it is already wrong. Abandon the import and then import it properly.

I could regurgitate the narrative from [Excel VBA - Convert Text to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date/30609676#30609676) but it has already been adequately described there. In short, bring the text back in with Data ► Get External Data ► From Text and specify the correct date conversion mask in the Text Import wizard. In VBA, use the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) and specify the xlColumnDataType as MDY.