# How do I convert text or string to time format using excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report and in columns L to Y I have the time of hh:mm:ss written as text and as a result I'm unable to do pivot calculations.

Is there an excel vba script that I can use to convert columns L:Y to the time value of hh:mm:ss?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date

Comment: You can copy the dates and paste them in Notepad, then copy the text from Notepad and paste in Excel.

Comment: Thanks slai, doing that works however I think it is impractical to be doing this each time the report is generated.  Was hoping for something more automated.

Comment: Clipboard copy and paste can be automated with `MSForms.DataObject`. Anyway, you can try something like `[L1:Y2].Value = [L1:Y2*1]`

Comment: Thanks Slai that works for me, much appreciated

Comment: @Slai: That is a valid answer :) Why not post it?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I can't try it, it probably has issues with blank cells, and the range is not auto extended to the last row.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but another similar solution is to copy a blank cell and add it to the range with Paste Special

or better, change the format and copy the values like this:

```
Set r = Intersect(UsedRange, Range("L:Y"))  ' only the used range in columns L to Y
r.NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"    ' military time format 24:59:59 ?
r.Value2 = r.Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA, you could perhaps put a formula in columns Z onwards, e.g. Z2's formula could say `=TIMEVALUE(L2)` etc.

Using VBA, you could use either the `CDate` or `TimeValue` functions to convert the string to a date/time.