# match two columns and display values from 3rd column using vlookup

Tags: excel

I am trying to perform vlookup on column A of sheet1 with column A of sheet2 and I have to display the value from column B of sheet2  to column B of sheet1.

The values in Column A of sheet1 and sheet2 are dates.So I am matching those two dates using vlookup and trying to display the third value,but its not working.My day column of sheet1 is
Day          | Final_Conversions
----------   | ------
27-10-2016
21-11-2016
15-12-2016
13-02-2017
And my sheet2 has
Day          | Conversions
----------   | ------
13-02-2017   | 23
15-12-2016   | 15
21-11-2016   | 400
23-11-2016   | 60

Now I want that if my date is there in sheet2 then conversion value should be dipslayed in sheet1.
 I tried this but ts not working =VLOOKUP(A2,'sheet2'!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)

Comment: I suspect that one of the date columns are text-that-look-like-dates and the other is true dates. I can see nothing wrong with your formula. Run Text-To-Columns, Fixed Width, DMY, Finish on both columns.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that one of the date columns are text-that-look-like-dates and the other are true dates. I can see nothing wrong with your formula. Run Text-To-Columns, Fixed Width, DMY, Finish on both columns.

[image]

Note that the dates in both Sheet1 and Sheet2 are right-aligned. This is the default cell alignment for numbers and dates. If you have not manually adjusted the cell alignment, yours are likely showing right-alignment in one worksheet and left-alignment (i.e. *text*) in the other.

On a related note, if you imported DMY data into a MDY system, see [Excel VBA - Convert Text to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date/30609676#30609676) for methods on repairing your data.