# excel: usedrange with columns of table

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to use UsedRange to select from first to last column from a table?

Here is the original code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("E").Cells
```

But it gets from first row to last maximum of Excel and I don't want this. So I tried to do something like this:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  

With ws.UsedRange.Columns("E2:E & LastRow").Cells
```

Although this doesn't seem to work here, so I was in doubt if there is a correct way to do this or the UsedRange it's not the best for that.

In addition, after this I want to use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date) code provided by Jeeped, but I need to know if it's possible to solve this problem first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the range directly,

```
with ws
    with .range(.cells(1, "E"), .cells(.rows.count, "E").end(xlup))
        'do something with the cells in column E
    end with
end with
```

You could use .UsedRange with Intersect

```
with Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.columns("E"))
    'do something with the cells in column E
end with
```

Comment: You should `Dim LastRow As Long`, not as an integer if you are going to use it.

Comment: thanks! it works now. I was really curious about UsedRange, I didn't know if I could type it like I do with Select.

Comment: Just remember that it is a property of a worksheet so (in the case above) it needs `ws` as a prefix to assign parent worksheet.

Comment: It seems that the first code works better than using Intersect, because it keeps draggin my table to the maximum Excel can reach

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but never use `.Select`.

```
With ws 
    .Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Select
End with
```