# Opening CSV files via Excel vba - date format change

Tags: vba, excel, csv

There are multiple questions concerning this problem already however none of the answers seem to solve the problem for me. The problem is this: I am having to edit a large number of .csv files so am doing this via Excel VBA. The first three columns are dates in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss and these dates are converted to the US format MDY when opening via

```
    set wb1 = Workbooks.Open (Filename:=savefolder & filename, Local:=True)
```

The most common answer for resolving this issue surrounds the known 'feature' that Excel will open CSV with the US dateformat unless the regional settings are used via the Local:=True but I have done this and it is still not working. Can anyone advise of a setting that might need changing to get the following code to work? thanks.

```
    Sub cleandata()
    dim wb1 as workbook
    dim ws1 as worksheet
    dim savefolder, filename as string

    savefolder = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\Clean Up Folder\"
    filename = dir(savefolder & "*")
    Do while len(filename) >0
           set wb1 = Workbooks.Open (Filename:=savefolder & filename, Local:=True)
           set ws1 = wb1.worksheets(1)
           'code related to what I am wanting to do to the data to 'clean it up'
           wb1.close true
           filename = dir()
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: if settings are not doing trick you can always reformat the dates in the `code related ...` part.

Comment: It sounds like you have done yopur research but how is this not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date/30609676#30609676)?

Comment: @Jeeped I had read and tried suggested solutions from several questions that refer to this issue as a result of importing CSVs, the question you link to had not come up in any of my google searches. I shall look at that and Tim William's answer on this thread and see if that resolves my issue. thanks

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thanks for the suggestion - I was hoping that I could find a way to fix it in import but yes, will fix afterthefact if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file using the `Data >> From Text` tool: in Step 3 of the process you can specify the date format of the incoming data.

Recording a macro will give you a start on the required code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `TextToColumns` function, you can use `FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4)` parameter.

I was having a similar issue and this worked for me (besides using `Local:=True`)

It only worked using both "solutions".

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@SMLBW

change your system short time and long time to the "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

Im hoping this should do the trick:

[image]