# Excel Date Formatting changes after using Find/Replace

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a bunch of dates in a volume which are in UK format but separated by dots not forward slashes.

Every time I run a macro to replace dots with dashes and use the line of code below, excel always seems to think that the months and day are the other way round

```
Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/"
NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

As an example:
03.07.18
Will become 07/03/2018 despite formatting as UK.

How can I keep the date as 03/07/2018

Comment: Do you have *dates* or *strings* ?

Comment: What does `31.07.18` become?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20375233/78522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try splitting into a `DateSerial`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range("B10")

    r = DateSerial(Split(r, ".")(2), Split(r, ".")(1), Split(r, ".")(0))

    r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Split [returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function).

What this means in plain English is that it takes your text string of `03.07.18`and splits it into three parts using the `.`.
So you end up with `03`, `07` and `18` within an array.

It might be easier to read as:

```
v = Split(r, ".")
r = DateSerial(v(2), v(1), v(0))
```

`DateSerial` takes three numbers (year, month and day) and returns a date.  The three parts of the Split are passed into this to create the date.

To process on a number of cells use:

```
Sub formatfixer()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("H5:H120")
        r = DateSerial(Split(r, ".")(2), Split(r, ".")(1), Split(r, ".")(0))
        r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! I have no idea what it means but thanks!

Comment: This seems like a stupid question, but I want to repeat this for Range H5:H120. I changed your code above from (“B10”) to (“H5:H120”) and it doesn’t work? Ideas?

Comment: That worked a treat and thank you for expanding on your answer. Top Man

Answer (score 1):

Easier to change the " **.** " in the *format* rather than in the *value*:

[image]

the code:

```
Sub formatfixer()
    Dim r As Range, formt As String
    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        formt = r.NumberFormat
        If InStr(1, formt, ".") > 0 Then
            r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After the replace, you can try to clear the date format and apply the NumberFormat method:

```
.Range(yourRange).ClearFormats
.Range(yourRange).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```