# Creating Outlook Appointment

Tags: vba, outlook, createitem

I have created a basic code wherein it will create an Outlook Appointment via VBA excel UserForm. My Problem, however, is that I am at lost on how to set the 'Start' based on the values of TextBox10 and Textbox11 since it does not accept both values of the textboxes together.

```
 Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem

    Candidate = TextBox2.Value + " " + TextBox1.Value
    InitialDate = TextBox10.Value
    InitialTime = TextBox11.Value

        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

            oAppt.Subject = Candidate
            oAppt.Start = TextBox10.Value + TextBox11.Value
            oAppt.Start = IntialTime
            oAppt.Recipients.Add ("Email@gmail.com")
            oAppt.Save
        Candidate = Sheets("Client Lineup List").Range("F" & lMaxRows + 1).Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use `Option Explicit` always.

Convert your TextBox values to a date/time first. Example below

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = CDate(TextBox10.Value & " " & TextBox11.Value)
```

However, in this case further considerations are required - check that a valid date and time is entered otherwise my example code above will error out. One simple part solution is to use a `DatePicker` instead of `TextBox10`. There used to be a DateTimePicker in VB, but I am not sure where the current equivalent in VBA is now.

In addition, check how I have concatenated the strings (with a space in between), use "&", not "+" which can have interesting side effects, especially if you have not set `Option Explicit` and not declared your variables (making them `Variant`).

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your TextBox values to a date/time.

You could quickly convert a column of text that resembles dates into actual dates with the VBA equivalent of the worksheet's Data ► Text-to-Columns command.

```
(TextBox10.Value & " " & TextBox11.Value).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
```

Note: you should check that a  valid date and time.

For more information, you can refer to this link:

[Excel VBA - Convert Text to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375233/excel-vba-convert-text-to-date)

Comment: However, the OP is using Outlook which is why Excel's `DATEVALUE` or Access's `DATESERIAL` don't apply.