# Convert string to Date using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a text to a date using VBA but I keep getting Type Mismatch Error. I have tried to use CDate and DateValue functions.

My date string is like -

```
Feb 12, 2020 6:00:00 PM
```

and I want the output to be -

```
20200212.
```

Please advise.

Comment: is the date a true date, does it change when you apply a different number format?  If so then just format the date: `yyyymmdd`.

Comment: The format function is not converting it because the info is coming from a different system as text field.

Comment: Excel's `DateValue` function understands that string perfectly well, as do `VBA.CDate` and `VBA.DateValue` functions, but I'm on an en-US locale. See the "caveat" quoteblock in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30609676/1188513)

Comment: What is your Windows language?